# Must an infinite subset of a compact Hausdorff space contain a *sequential* accumulation point?

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology, convergence-divergence, examples-counterexamples

**Def (Sequential Accumulation Point):** Given a topological space $(X,\tau)$ and a subset $S\subseteq X$, we say that $a\in X$ is a *sequential* accumulation point if there exists $(s_n)_{n\geq1}\subseteq S\setminus\{a\}$ that converges to $a$.

The name comes from the following analogy. We say that $a\in X$ is an accumulation point of $S\subseteq X$ whenever $a\in\text{cl}_X(S\setminus\{a\})$. So, if we consider the sequential closure of a set (i.e. the set of points in $X$ that can be expressed as a limit of a sequence of the said set), we have that $a\in X$ is a sequential accumulation point of $S$ whenever $a\in\text{scl}_X(S\setminus\{a\})$.

Now, we know that in compact Hausdorff spaces every infinite subset must have an accumulation point. My question then is

> **Q:** Must every infinite subset $S\subseteq X$ of a compact Hausdorff space have a sequential accumulation point?

Note that, if true, this fact would be stronger as any sequential accumulation point is an accumulation point since $\text{scl}_X(S\setminus\{a\})\subseteq\text{cl}_X(S\setminus\{a\})$. Also, the answer to this question is affirmative if $X$ is first-countable as first-countable implies [Fréchet-Urysohn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet%E2%80%93Urysohn_space). But not every compact Hausdorff space is first-countable. If there's a counterexample, could $S\subseteq X$ be [$G_\delta$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%CE%B4_set) with no sequential accumulation point if $X$ is compact and Hausdorff?

Comment: Yes, there are counterexamples.  $\beta\Bbb{N}$, the Stone-Cěch compactification of $\Bbb{N}$ (as a discrete space) is compact Hausdorff, extremally disconnected.  In an extremally disconnected space,  all convergent sequences are eventually constant.

Comment: @ChadK This should be an official answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For one definition of a Stone-Čech compactification and some of its properties see Eduard Čech 'On Bicompact Spaces' section II.

For a proof that projective objects in the category of compact Hausdorff spaces are extremally disconnected see Andrew Gleason 'Projective Topological Spaces' Theorem 1.2.

For a proof that sequences in extremally disconnected spaces are eventually constant see same paper by Gleason, Theorem 1.3.

Proving that $\beta\Bbb{N}$ is projective in the category of compact Hausdorff  spaces is easy from the universal property of a Stone-Čech compactification, but if you can't figure it out, it's in John Rainwater 'A Note on Projective Resolutions' Lemma 3.

A projective object in the category of compact Hausdorff spaces is one that has a similar universal property for projective objects in algebra - i.e. projective module over a ring.  An epimorphism in topological spaces is a surjective continuous map.